# Patch axios vue js cannot get id

Tags: vue.js, axios

Hi I try to make patch method on edit function. When I do testing of the function , it cant get id of the post

here the edit method

```
methods: {
    editPost: function () {
      try {
        let response = axios.patch(
          "http://post-management-backend.test/api/posts/" + this.id,
          this.propObj,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json",
              Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
            },
          }
        );
        return response;
      } catch (error) {
        window.alert(error);
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  },
};
```

here the props method

```
props: {
    propObj: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
      default: function () {
        return {
          id: "",
          title: "",
          description: "",
        };
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Try `this.propObj.id`

Comment: I check on request payload id: ""

Comment: maybe because it's actually empty, did you pass the prop data from router / other component? Because the defailt value of `propObj.id` is `""`